# Selectnodes for XmlNode cannot find Relationship nodes

Tags: c#, xml

Hullo,

I am trying to use XmlNode's SelectNodes method to get the ID information below. I need the ID to tie it to an image reference from it. I've used selectnodes with namespaces before successfully, but I think it has something to do with the namespace for relationships specifically, since it's defining namespaces within this node.

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http:blah">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="blah" pkg:padding="512">...</pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="blah" pkg:contentType="blah" pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http:blah">
        <Relationship Id="rId8" Type="http:blah" Target="media/image2.png/>
        <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http:blah" Target="media/image3.png/>
```

Things I've tried that have returned no results:

```
...SelectNodes("//pkg:package/pkg:part/pkg:xmlData/Relationships/Relationship[@Type='blah'", nsm);  
...SelectNodes("//Relationships", nsm);  
...SelectNodes("//xmlns:Relationships", nsm); 
...SelectNodes("//Relationship", nsm);  
...SelectNodes("//Relationship[@Type='http:blah'], nsm);
```

and so on and so on. I hoped this would help but it didnt work.

here is my setup of nsm...

```
nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldocin.NameTable);
            nsm.AddNamespace ("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            nsm.AddNamespace("pkg", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage");
            nsm.AddNamespace("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            nsm.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");
            nsm.AddNamespace("pic", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture");
            nsm.AddNamespace("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
```

If I use pkg:xmlData in the select query works just fine, so I know I have the rest of my code working fine.The problem is specifically with the "Relationship" nodes.

The actual information I need is the ID so i can correlate it to the target so i know which image to use when i hit that ID going through the document.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there no default namespace declaration(`xmlns=...`)? If so, you can add that namespace to your namespace manager, so that you can target the elements `Relationship` (etc.) too.

Comment: that doesn't work. if i try to add xmlns as a namespace declaration i get a "Prefix "xmlns" is reserved for use by XML." error

Comment: You should add the default namespace as e.g. `ns` (or whatever you like), so you can target the `Relationship` node like so: `//ns:Relationship`. If I remember correctly, that worked for me once.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're the MAN! (or WOMAN, perhaps). That worked!

Comment: :D nice! I'll create an answer, so people landing on this page having the same question will find the answer easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the default namespace to your namespace manager, using some key (for instance `ns`):

```
nsm.AddNamespace("ns", ...)
```

then you can target the nodes of this default namespace with that key:

```
.. SelectNodes("//ns:Relationship", nsm);
```

Comment: That namespace was already defined as `pkg`. You can just do `SelectNodes("//pkg:Relationship", nsm)` without adding a new namespace to the `XmlNamespaceManager`

Comment: I don't think he mentioned what the default namespace was (I think the `blah`s replaced the actual namespaces). So, we can't assume it's the same as `pkg`.

Comment: I was thinking of `r` in my previous comment based on the naming but that was wrong as well, so you're correct. Not sure why the XML was modified.

Comment: I Know I tried r at one point. I'm not sure I ever tried pkg.